# Textbox taking wrong values

Tags: asp.net

I am adding two numbers in `asp.net` by web service. But it's showing the wrong result.
When I debug it the text boxes are taking another value than what I put down in text boxes..
If someone has any idea about this, please let me know. Why is it happening?

Code in Web service:-

```
public int ADD(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Default.aspx.cs:-

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == true)
    {
        WebService1 ws = new WebService1();
        int res = ws.ADD(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text), Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text));
        Label3.Visible = true;
        LblReslt.Visible = true;
        LblReslt.Text = res.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I think your problem is in line 42 of the webserver.

Comment: There's a big difference between helping out with your code and guessing what your code is.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the second textbox to TextBox2:

```
int res = ws.ADD(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text), Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several little things that can be cleared up.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack) //an if expression already tests for true/false. Since IsPostBack is already a Boolean, then testing it for equality to true is redundant.
    {
    }
}
```

By definition, you're going to be in a postback if the event handler for your button is clicked. So you don't need to check if it's a postback. And you're adding the same TextBox twice. I suggest you add the value of a second checkbox. When in doubt, step through the code with your debugger to see what's going on.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     WebService1 ws = new WebService1();
     int res = ws.ADD(Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text), Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text));
     Label3.Visible = true;
     LblReslt.Visible = true;
     LblReslt.Text = res.ToString();
}
```